# Android Studio: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null

Tags: android, error-handling, kotlin

I'm currently working on my first project, so I'm sorry if it sounds like a stupid question.

I'm having trouble with a piece of code that should attempt to create a Firebase acccount with the email and password provided in the text boxes in the UI when you click a button. Instead, whenever I click that button, the app crashes with the error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null.

Code:

```
    //Create new User
    var email = emailID.text.toString().trim()
    var pwd = passwordID.text.toString().trim()


    create_acc_button.setOnClickListener{

        mAuth!!.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, 
        pwd).addOnCompleteListener(this
        ) { task: Task<AuthResult> ->
            if (task.isSuccessful){
                var user:FirebaseUser = mAuth!!.currentUser!!
                Log.d("User", user.email.toString())
            }else{
                Log.d("Error:", task.toString())
            }
        }
    }
```

Logcat:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq.zzgm(Unknown Source:10)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.david.mykotlinfirebaseintro.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:37)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this way; email and pwd variables filled at first start. Your changes are not effect the variables.

You must move this lines into the clicklistener.

```
 //Create new User
var email = emailID.text.toString().trim()
var pwd = passwordID.text.toString().trim()
```

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thank you! So the problem was that the text was changing, but it was too late for the variables to be updated?

Comment: Exactly! In this way, you get texts when the user clicks on the button.

Answer (score 0):

surround code with condition in button click

```
if (email != null || !email.isEmpty()) {
     //your positive code
} else {
     //your negative code    
}
```